# URL Routing not working in Windows shared hosting, perfectly working in Local Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, server, web-config

I am using PHP framework to build my website

I am getting 404 - File not found error when try to access a lik like below.

https://ex.example.com/example

But the index file is routing and working perfect (below link go to the index file)

https://ex.example.com/

I am using the following URL structure. note that the .php extention is omitted as all frameworks

```
https://'domain' / 'module' / 'function' / 'parameter'
```

I am struggling to do the routing in the windows hosting, I need to clarify 2 things

1. Will the .htaccess file works on IIS (Windows) shared server? If not how to convert the following .htaccess to web.config code (I am new to web.config).

> ```
> Options -Indexes
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
>
> RewriteRule !^static index.php [QSA,L]
> ```

2. is there anything else I am missing to consider in windows shared hosting?

I am using
PHP 5.6

Answer (score 1):

There is no .htaccess on IIS. You can use the web.config XML file for that.

For instance, I used this config with my virtual server on IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Plus, you can see this help section on iis.net to know more about how to translate .htaccess to web.config: https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: Thank you for the valuable link, unfortunately still couldn't figure it out. stuck with the `RewriteRule !^static index.php [QSA,L]` part